# Cannot disable autocommit?

Tags: mysql, commit, autocommit

I have Ubuntu 12.04 guest VM with a MySQL 5.5.35 instance on it. I cannot seem to bypass / turn off `autocommit` feature...

I wanted to try out some scenarios related to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;`, so I opened two database sessions - one from the MySQL workbench on the VM itself, and another one from `mysql` CLI, on my Windows host. Whatever I do in either of the two sessions is instantly visible in another. Autocommit or no autocommit set, transaction or no transaction, explicit commit or no explicit commit...

I tried the following:

1) disabling it through configuration

```
[mysqld]  
autocommit = 0
```

which effectively set the global `autocommit` variable to OFF, according to `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES`. Does not work.

2) running this command as the very first one

```
set autocommit=0;
select @@autocommit;
+--------------+
| @@autocommit |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

Does not work.

3) opening an explicit transaction

```
start transaction; // tried begin; as well
...
commit;
```

Does not work.

The damn database acts as auto-commit is always ON, for each single `INSERT / UPDATE` statement, even though database settings and variables show differently... `commit` statement always returns `0 rows affected`.

Am I missing something here...?
Could this relate to users / privileges in any possible way...?

Comment: are you using a transaction-capable DB engine? e.g. if you're using myisam, then there are no transactions, and auto commit would stay on regardless.

Comment: Marc, seems that you are right... I performed all the tests on MyISAM table without even thinking to do so much as to check the engine type... Please, make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a transaction-capable DB engine? e.g. if you're using MyISAM, then there are no transactions, and auto commit would stay on regardless